# How to build a release version binary in Go?

Tags: c, go, build, release

In C, we can build a debug version or a release version of the binary files (the object files and the executable). How can we do this in Go?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In Go, it isn't typical to have a debug version or a release version.

By default, `go build` combines symbol and debug info with binary files. However, you can remove the symbol and debug info with `go build -ldflags "-s -w"`.

Comment: There's some documentation on this here - https://golang.org/doc/gdb#Introduction.

Comment: You're right, but I think there's a good reason it's not typical to strip symbols--if you get a report of a panic out in the wild, for example, it'd be great to have the symbols there for an informative stacktrace.

Comment: I think "-s" (omit symbol table and debug info) already includes "-w" (omit DWARF symbol table), so there should be no need to specify both. With the executable I tried this on, "-s -w" gives exactly the same size as "-s" alone.

Comment: It would appear that -s doesn't affect GOOS=darwin

Comment: Only startup-time changes.

Comment: Just made some experiments on my Mac. Results: -s does not imply -w, binary size with/without -s is the same. -w reduces binary from 12 to 8MB. ALSO: there's NO difference in stack-traces between "go build" and "-s -w" builds. Of course it's just for my software, probably there are 
 corner cases.

Comment: The -s flag removes all symbols (including the DWARF symbol table, which -w removes.) So you only need -s, I think.

Comment: Hello world goes from 2MB to 1.4MB :)

Answer (score 28):

You can instruct the linker to strip debug symbols by using

```
go install -ldflags '-s'
```

I just tried it on a fairly large executable (one of the [GXUI](https://github.com/google/gxui) samples), and this reduced it from ~16M to ~10M. As always, your mileage may vary...

[Here](https://golang.org/cmd/link/) is a full list of all linker options.