# How to create a go file for “release”?

Tags: go, qml, release

I want to make a Golang File For "Release".

This is my command:

```
go build -o testi.exe -ldflags "-H windowsgui"
```

What is the correct way? My code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    //"github.com/chai2010/qml"
    "github.com/go-qml/qml"
)
func main() {
    if err := qml.Run(run); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
func run() error {
    engine := qml.NewEngine()
    engine.On("quit", func() { os.Exit(0) })

    component, err := engine.LoadString("hello.qml", qmlHello)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    window := component.CreateWindow(nil)
    window.Show()
    window.Wait()
    return nil
}

const qmlHello = `
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 320; height: 240
    color: "lightgray"
    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello world!"
        y: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
`
```

I installed : go1.5.windows-386.

Comment: what do you mean by 'For "Release"'?

Comment: In C ++ is two modes:Release  And Debug.example: in qt and c++
the program is 25.0 KB for "release" And for debug : 850 KB .

Comment: It might mean something in your IDE, but that's not a C++ thing. I'm not sure what you expect Go to build differently for Release, if you don't have anything specifically configured for not-Release.

Comment: size total program with dll : 743mb
Everything that needs:
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Cored.dll
Qt5Guid.dll
Qt5Networkd.dll
Qt5Qmld.dll
Qt5Quickd.dll
Qt5Widgetsd.dll

Comment: See other discussion on this question at https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/create-go-file-for-release/1415

Comment: How big is your binary? Go doesn't build any of those other artifacts, and it's up to you to provide them in some way.

Comment: I Ran exe file.
It Warned:
The program can't start because Qt5Cored.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
This program Compiled for "debug"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a release version binary in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599209/how-to-build-a-release-version-binary-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by JimB, Dave Cheney, and others:

- There is no "RELEASE" for Golang
- Golang executables are large, that is [normal](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary)
- Yes, you have to provide to DLL files if you force linking shared libraries
- Yes, those libraries might be large.
- There is nothing wrong, just let go use the defaults

Comment: I have created release file. 
But It has a problem in another computer now.
The go file , isn't execute in another computer now.

Comment: The problem was solved.
I used the following programs:
procmon.exe