# Passing an optimization flag to a Go compiler?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments, compiler-optimization

To compile a Go program you type `go build myprogram.go`, can you pass an optimization flags along or the code is always compiled in the same way? I am talking about speed optimizations, code size optimizations or other optimizations.

I know if you use `gccgo` you just pass `-O2` or `-O0` but my question is about an official Go compiler `go`.

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/compile/ has an option to *disable* optimizations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a release version binary in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599209/how-to-build-a-release-version-binary-in-go)

Comment: @phuclv: The linked duplicate is missing answers that point out the possibility of disabling optimization and inlining.  It's fine to point out that it's normal not to do that, but if optimized vs. non-optimized is not even useful at all for a Go debug build, then these questions aren't duplicates.  (Useful for them to link to each other, though.)

Answer (score 29):

Actually no explicit flags, this Go wiki [page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations) lists optimizations done by the Go compiler and there was a discussion around this topic in [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/rwpP0iF1AKE/5ZvWLNjSIJkJ) groups.

You can turn off optimization and inlining in Go gc compilers for debugging.

```
-gcflags '-N -l'
```

- `-N` : Disable optimizations
- `-l` :   Disable inlining

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking to optimize the binary size, you can omit the symbol table, debug information and the DWARF symbol table by passing `-s` and `-w` to the [Go linker](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/link):

```
$ go build -o mybinary -ldflags="-s -w" src.go
```

([source blog post which includes some benchmarks](https://words.filippo.io/shrink-your-go-binaries-with-this-one-weird-trick/))