# why is the Go build faster than the Rust one?

Tags: performance, go, rust

I am practicing at leedcode writing solution in golang and rust.
I wrote a solution for this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/ in golang and in rust

```go
package main

func letterCombinations(digits string) []string {
    if len(digits) == 0 {
        return []string{}
    }

    letters := [][]string{
        {},
        {},
        {"a", "b", "c"},
        {"d", "e", "f"},
        {"g", "h", "i"},
        {"j", "k", "l"},
        {"m", "n", "o"},
        {"p", "q", "r", "s"},
        {"t", "u", "v"},
        {"w", "x", "y", "z"},
    }

    var gen func(index int, digits string) []string
    gen = func(index int, digits string) []string {
        result := make([]string, 0)
        row := letters[int(digits[index]-'0')]
        index++
        for _, letter := range row {
            if index < len(digits) {
                for _, res := range gen(index, digits) {
                    result = append(result, letter+res)
                }
            } else {
                result = append(result, letter)
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    return gen(0, digits)
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        letterCombinations("23456789")
    }
}
```

and this in rust

```rust
struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn letter_combinations(digits: String) -> Vec<String> {
        if digits.len() == 0 {
            return vec![];
        }

        let letters: [[char; 5]; 10] = [
            [0 as char, '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            [0 as char, '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            [3 as char, 'a', 'b', 'c', '0'], // 2
            [3 as char, 'd', 'e', 'f', '0'], // 3
            [3 as char, 'g', 'h', 'i', '0'], // 4
            [3 as char, 'j', 'k', 'l', '0'], // 5
            [3 as char, 'm', 'n', 'o', '0'], // 6
            [4 as char, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'], // 7
            [3 as char, 't', 'u', 'v', '0'], // 8
            [4 as char, 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], // 9
        ];

        fn gen(index: usize, digits: &str, letters: [[char; 5]; 10]) -> Vec<String> {
            let result_capacity = (4 as usize).pow(digits.len() as u32);
            let mut result: Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(result_capacity);
            let iletters = digits.chars().nth(index).unwrap().to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize;
            let row = letters[iletters];
            let index = index + 1;
            for i in 1..= row[0] as usize {
                if index < digits.len() {
                    let res = gen(index, digits, letters);
                    for j in 0..res.len() {
                        let mut line = String::with_capacity(res[j].len() + 1);
                        line.push(row[i]);
                        line.push_str(&res[j]);
                        result.push(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    result.push(row[i].to_string());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        return gen(0, &digits, letters);
    }
}

fn main() {
    for _i in 0..10000 {
        Solution::letter_combinations(String::from("23456789"));
    }
}
```

Where I run each solution through 10 000 iterations.
Golang solution takes 60 seconds on my laptop.
Rust solution takes 556 seconds which is about 10 times slower.
I guess it because **golang** garbage collector does not return heap memory to OS during program and use pre-allocated memory for each iteration.
But **rust** every call of function letterCombinations() allocates memory from OS and frees it back. So rust slower.
Am I correct?

Comment: Did you compile the Rust code in release mode?

Comment: [Don't use LeetCode for Rust.](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/learning-rust-in-2020.md#leetcode)

Comment: >  Did you compile the Rust code in release mode? 
you are right I used debug mode. I have tried with release and rust solution takes about as golang one. Thank you. I am new in rust and did not realized debug mode can be so slow.

Comment: [Why is my Rust program slower than the equivalent Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25255736/3650362)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted elsewhere (e.g., [Why is my Rust program slower than the equivalent Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25255736/1256452)), if you compile Rust code in *debug* mode, it tends to be slow.  If you turn on optimization, it tends to be much faster.

It's worth mentioning here that Rust compilers will do a great deal of optimization *if you let them* (or tell them).  [The `cargo build` system will do this when run in *release* mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-01-release-profiles.html).  This optimization can make debugging very hard!  So if you're trying to get code *working*, you probably don't want to do this yet.

Go compilers traditionally just do relatively simple optimization.<sup>1</sup>  So `go build` currently doesn't have an optimization level or flag, except for [`-N` to disable optimization and `-l` to disable inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45003259/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>This optimization is not useless, but it's not the kind of super-fancy makes-following-your-code-in-the-debugger-impossible optimization that `rustc` does at high optimization levels.