# golang strip symbols with go build vs strip

Tags: go, strip, debug-symbols

Why does stripping symbols differ between `strip` and `go build -ldflags "-s -w"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599209/how-to-build-a-release-version-binary-in-go))?

```
$ go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o primes_no_symbols_from_go_build primes.go
$ go build -o primes primes.go && strip -s primes -o primes_no_symbols_from_strip
$ objdump -D primes_no_symbols_from_go_build > primes_no_symbols_from_go_build.human
$ objdump -D primes_no_symbols_from_strip > primes_no_symbols_from_strip.human
$ grep -rn "add" primes_no_symbols_from_go_build.human | wc -l
149568
$ grep -rn "add" primes_no_symbols_from_strip.human | wc -l
149556
```

what can account for these changes? (the underlying go program, probably irrelevant, is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280753/forbid-inlining-in-golang)).

Answer (score 1):

strip and ld tools are OS specific, from

```
man strip
```

> When strip is used with no options on an executable file, it checks
> that file  to  see
> if  it  uses  the dynamic link editor.  If it does, the effect of the strip command is
> the same as using the -u and -r options. If the file does not  use  the  dynamic  link
> editor,  the effect of strip without any options is the same as using the -s option of
> ld(1).  The options -S, -x, and -X have the same effect as  the  ld(1)  options.   The
> options  to strip(1) can be combined to trim the symbol table to just what is desired.

i.e. most ld's don't have -w, which means on OSX "suppress all warning messages"

on Linux/Debian

```
1187840 Jul  7 09:05 primes_no_symbols_from_go_build_s
1187840 Jul  7 09:05 primes_no_symbols_from_go_build_s_w
1755360 Jul  7 09:05 primes_simple_go_build
1187004 Jul  7 09:06 primes_simple_go_build_strip
```

on OSX

```
2076146 Jul  7 16:02 primes_no_symbols_from_go_build_s
1580786 Jul  7 16:02 primes_no_symbols_from_go_build_s_w
2076146 Jul  7 16:02 primes_simple_go_build
1997872 Jul  7 16:04 primes_simple_go_build_strip
```