# _cgo_topofstack@@Base in a stripped binary

Tags: go, x86, disassembly, strip, objdump

What does `_cgo_topofstack@@Base` mean in the context of a stripped binary coming from Go?

```
$ cat simple.go
package main
import
(
    "net"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", ":7777")
    listener, _ := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    conn, _ := listener.Accept()
    daytime := time.Now().String()+strconv.Itoa(0xdeadface)
    conn.Write([]byte(daytime))
}
```

The code is supposed to be stripped - what does `_cgo_topofstack@@Base` mean?

```
$ go build -gcflags=-l -ldflags "-s -w" -o simple_wo_symbols simple.go
$ objdump -D -S simple_wo_symbols > simple_wo_symbols.human
$ sed -n "198899,198904p" simple_wo_symbols.human
  4b9860:   e8 db c1 fb ff          callq  475a40 <_cgo_topofstack@@Base+0xe4c0>
  4b9865:   48 8b 44 24 18          mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
  4b986a:   48 89 44 24 70          mov    %rax,0x70(%rsp)
  4b986f:   48 8b 4c 24 20          mov    0x20(%rsp),%rcx
  4b9874:   48 89 4c 24 40          mov    %rcx,0x40(%rsp)
  4b9879:   ba ce fa ad de          mov    $0xdeadface,%edx
```

**EDIT** (better specification of the question):

- why does this symbol exist in a *stripped* binary?
- ratify [peter-cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) claim: called function is *completely unrelated* to the function at `_cgo_topofstack@@Base`, and it is an `objdump` (weird?) thing to add this (irrelevant and redundant) info
- maybe related to [this(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282531/golang-strip-symbols-with-go-build-vs-strip): is there a Go-idiomatic way of stripping?!

Comment: I don't know Go very well at all, but `_cgo_topofstack@@Base` is a symbol that does still exist.  That call is to an address `0xe4c0` beyond that, whatever function lives there.

Comment: What more do you want to know?  The actual function `_cgo_topofstack@@Base` is irrelevant to what you're calling, but when searching backwards from the actual target address, that was the most recent one `objdump` found.  If you're curious about what a function like `_cgo_topofstack@@Base` would do, it probably returns RSP (or not, given VonC's answer; "top" and "bottom" aren't always clear terms for stacks that grow downward).  If you're wondering about the `@@` that happens to be part of the symbol name, you should edit your question.

Comment: I edited my question to explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_cgo_topofstack@@Base` is a symbol that does still exist for some reason in your stripped binary. Your call is to an address `0xe4c0` beyond that, whatever function lives there, completely unrelated to the actual `_cgo_topofstack` code.

It's normal for disassemblers to describe addresses as symbol+offset.

That style makes sense for data arrays (e.g. compiling something like `x = global_array[10]` into a load from `global_array+40`, if the symbol for `global_array` is still around), and for jumps within functions.  It's usually not helpful for cases like this, other than to let you see what's nearby, and to have smaller numbers to look at.

Instead of implementing fancy logic to decide whether or not to bother printing a `symbol+offset` version of an address, instead of just the numeric absolute address, it's much easier (and no risk of being wrong) for assemblers to just always do it.  Search backward from the address and take the first symbol found.  Or for addresses before the first symbol in a section, print as `foo - 0x...`.  It's up to humans to use judgement and experience to make sense of the output, especially when looking at disassembly of stripped binaries.

(There isn't a flag a disassembler can look at to detect a stripped binary or not; detecting this would be a matter of a heuristic like noticing that most direct `call` targets are to addresses without their own symbol.)

AFAIK, GNU Binutils `objdump` doesn't have an option not to print symbolic versions of addresses.  `--no-addresses` does something different.

---

I'm not sure what the `@@Base` is about.  It doesn't seem to be unique to Go, though.  On my x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux system, `objdump -d /bin/ls` (which is a stripped PIE executable) shows a lot of addresses as things like `22d60 <_obstack_memory_used@@Base+0xc2a0>`.  So that's the symbol that happened to be last before the bulk of the code for that program.

Other cases of `@@` include glibc symbol ABI versioning in that same binary, e.g. `23298 <optarg@@GLIBC_2.2.5>`.  This Arch Linux binary was compiled on an up-to-date Arch Linux system, not actually linked against an ancient glibc 2.2.5, but I think that means `optarg`'s type or something hasn't changed since glibc 2.2.5.  And probably not since earlier, but 2.2.5 might have been when glibc started naming symbols this way.  Take this paragraph with a big grain of salt because I don't really know how `libc.so` arranges for `ld` to substitute symbol names like `stderr` with these `@@` versioned names, or the history of this.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding what `_cgo_topofstack` is about, you can see it [introduced in its current form in Go 1.4](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1aa65fe8d4c0ebdd754480d281f378fcd1c42cea), [original name `cgo_topofstack`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1b6807bb069c528447270c3d6c66c5c7597f388f)

(But, as noted by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297387/cgo-topofstackbase-in-a-stripped-binary/68333139?noredirect=1#comment120768264_68333139), this does not explain why that symbol would still be present in a [stripped binary](https://blog.filippo.io/shrink-your-go-binaries-with-this-one-weird-trick/#butfirstletmestripthebinary))

```golang
// Called from cgo wrappers, this function returns g->m->curg.stack.hi.
// Must obey the gcc calling convention.
TEXT cgo_topofstack(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    get_tls(CX)
    MOVL    g(CX), AX
    MOVL    g_m(AX), AX
    MOVL    m_curg(AX), AX
    MOVL    (g_stack+stack_hi)(AX), AX
    RET
```

It was for fixing [golang/go/issue 8771](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8771):

> ### `cmd/cgo`: C functions that return values fail if they call a Go callback that copies the stack

> Cgo uses a wrapper function that calls C code, passing the address of the stack frame.
> This wrapper function is compiled by GCC, and it calls the real function written by the user.
>
> The user's function is permitted to call Go callbacks.
> Those Go callbacks will run on the stack of the original caller.
> They may cause a stack copy.
>
> If the stack gets copied during a Go callback, then the caller of the GCC-compiled wrapper is running in a different location.
> The stack frame pointer used by the GCC-compiled wrapper is not updated, since of course the stack copier knows nothing about GCC-compiled code.
> I don't think this is a problem for the arguments to the function; they have already been copied out of the stack frame when the wrapper calls the real function.
>
> However, it is a problem for C functions that return a value.
> The wrapper will take the value returned by the C function, and store it using its pointer to the stack frame. That pointer will not have been updated if a stack copy occurs.
> In other words, the wrapper may store the return value on the old stack, not the new one.

[CL 144130043](https://codereview.appspot.com/144130043) adds:

> ### cgo: adjust return value location to account for stack copies.

> During a cgo call, the stack can be copied.
> This copy invalidates the pointer that cgo has into the return value area.
>
> To fix this problem, pass the address of the location containing the stack
> top value (which is in the G struct).
> For cgo functions which return values, read the stktop before and after the cgo call to compute the adjustment necessary to write the return value.

It was amended with [commit e1364a6](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/e1364a6d0ecd5ba50845f416bb3c016bc54a3648).

---

The '@@' part should be the result of an [option of `objdump`](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/binutils-stable/html/binutils/binutils.html#objdump), `--symbols`

> Displays the entries in symbol table section of the file, if it has one.
> If a symbol has version information associated with it then this is displayed as well.
>
> The version string is displayed as a suffix to the symbol name, preceeded by an `@` character. For example `foo@VER_1`.
>
> If the version is the default version to be used when resolving unversioned references to the symbol then it is displayed as a suffix preceeded by two `@` characters. For example `foo@@VER_2`.

Comment: But note that the OP's code is *not* calling that, this just happens to be the closest preceding symbol to the target address still present in the stripped binary, `0xe4c0` bytes before it.  (So it's many pages earlier, and this function is tiny.)  This is a useful and interesting answer to *some* question, but *this* question would take some editing before it's a good place to put this answer.  (And it's unclear if that's what the querent wants.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree. I focused on what could generate that symbol.

Comment: I think you should at least note at the top of the answer that this isn't a call to that function, and that you're just explaining what that symbol is about.  (If you could explain the significance of `@@Base` in symbol names, that might also be good.)  Maybe I missed it, but I also don't see an explicit explanation of why that symbol would still be present in a stripped binary.

Comment: I edited my question so it better explains what I meant. thanks.